# How to sort multiple columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need your help!

I have this on my database.

```
table name: tblClient

-------------------------------------------------
id        | stars1       | stars2      | stars3 |
-------------------------------------------------
1         | 5            | 0           | 0      |
2         | 4            | 0           | 0      |
3         | 0            | 5           | 0      |
4         | 0            | 4           | 0      |
5         | 0            | 0           | 5      |
-------------------------------------------------
```

What is the SQL statement to come up with this output?

```
-------------------------------------------------
id        | stars1       | stars2      | stars3 |
-------------------------------------------------
1         | 5            | 0           | 0      |
3         | 0            | 5           | 0      |
5         | 0            | 0           | 5      |
2         | 4            | 0           | 0      |
4         | 0            | 4           | 0      |
-------------------------------------------------
```

I have done this `SELECT * FROM tblClient ORDER BY stars1 DESC,stars2 DESC,stars3 DESC,id ASC` but it seems the output is wrong.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What is the logic behind your output?

Comment: That output is not sorted in any way. `ORDER BY stars1,stars2` means it orders rows by `stars2` if and only if their `stars1` values are equal.

Comment: I don't see any sort order here

Comment: It seems an order is: "select rows order by maximum value among stars1, stars2, stars3" - i.e. first will be rows where at least one of three columns have 5 (5 is a maximum through all), then 4, e t.c. Probably order inside triplet of column also matters (i.e. first should be that with star1, then star2, then star3)

Comment: For me, the original rows' order seems to fit the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the query:

```
SELECT id,stars1, stars2 ,stars3
FROM(
  SELECT id,stars1, stars2 ,stars3, (stars1+stars2+stars3) as sum 
  FROM tblClient 
  GROUP by id
  ORDER BY sum desc) as sorted;
```

I made a fiddle for you, Check it here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd5d3/10

Comment: No, since SUM will be same across 3 columns (i.e. there will be no order with first - star1 value, then - star2 value, then - star3 value)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM tblClient ORDER BY stars1 desc,stars2 desc,stars3 desc,id desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM tblCleint ORDER BY stars1+stars2+stars3 desc;

This is the solution of your Query...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  tblClients 
ORDER BY 
  stars1*1.1+stars2*1.05+stars3 DESC
```

Comment: thanks,

this query also works for me:

SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  tblClient 
ORDER BY 
  stars1+stars2+stars3 DESC

Comment: pretty sure that if you don't assign weights or order by the columns it will rank the sum, but not starting by a particular column